# Failed to display Jupyter Widget of typeHBox; widgets JavaScript library missing?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tqdm

I am trying to use [keras-tqdm](https://github.com/bstriner/keras-tqdm) to get a progress bar in my Jupyter notebook when training models with Keras, but I'm stuck on the following error message:

> Failed to display Jupyter Widget of type HBox.
>
> If you're reading this message in the Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab
>   Notebook, it may mean that the widgets JavaScript is still loading. If
>   this message persists, it likely means that the widgets JavaScript
>   library is either not installed or not enabled. See the [Jupyter
>   Widgets Documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html) for setup instructions.
>
> If you're reading this message in another frontend (for example, a
>   static rendering on GitHub or NBViewer), it may mean that your
>   frontend doesn't currently support widgets.

I have visited the [documentation page](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html) that they link to and have executed their commands. Nothing seems to work, and I'm lost as to what the next step is.

Earlier it just said that I had an old version of the JavaScript widgets, and that I needed a newer one. I followed various instructions in order to try to update the JavaScript widgets, and that's how this happened.

To be clear, here is the command from the documentation:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

when I run it, I get the following:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36:
#
ipywidgets                7.1.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

where py36 is the environment that I'm using.

What can I do next?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the notebook? I ran into the same issue and restarting the notebook did the trick

Comment: @vladimir.gorea It didn't help for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Do you use new "jupyter lab" by any chance?

Extension system of JupyterLab is quite different. I got it working on CentOS like this:

1. You must have nodejs installed. Probably the easiest way is to follow [official documentation for your OS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).
   Example for CentOS (assuming EPEL repo is installed):

   `sudo yum install nodejs`
2. npm should be able to install packages, so [if you are behind proxy](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/):

   `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
   npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`
3. Follow [ipywidgets install instructions](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html):

   `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`

The last command uses npm to install nodejs package for ipywidgets and its dependencies.

Comment: I was actually using the old Jupyter, version 4.3.1.